# Espresso. Error performing 'load adapter data'

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a ListView, which shows data from a database.

```
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();


    String[] from = new String[]{DB.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, DB.COLUMN_LASTNAME};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};        

    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, null, from, to, 0);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    lvData.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    lvData.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
```

It shows the first name and last name from the database as a list of items:
[Click to UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcBaa.jpg)

So, today I tried to use Espresso with this app and I can't find a way to click on the item containing the text.

When I use:

```
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lvData))
    .atPosition(3)
    .perform(click());
```

It works perfectly. But I want to click on the item containing the corresponding item's text.

What I tried so far (everything I've found at stackoverflow, google, github, etc.):

```
onView(allOf(withText("Ivan Ivanov"))).perform(click())

onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(MainActivity.class)),is("Ivan Ivanov")))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lvData))
            .perform(click());

onData(hasToString(startsWith("v")))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lvData))
            .atPosition(0).perform(click());

onData(instanceOf(MainActivity.class))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lvData))
            .atPosition(0)
            .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Ivan Ivanov"))));

onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withContentDescription("Ivan Ivanov"))
            .atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

So, maybe is there are differences between the string "Ivan Ivanov" and the item, which contains data from the database: `firstName`+`lastName`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [CursorMatchers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/CursorMatchers.html) to match items in your listview.

`onData()` works against the **data** in your adapter, not the actual view. In your case the ListView is backed by the CursorAdapter, hence the CursorMatcher.

And the usage is the following:

```
onData(withRowString(DB.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, "Ivan")).perform(click());
```