# Testing RecyclerView if it has data with Espresso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ui-automation, android-espresso

I need to write a test to click, let's say on the first item in my RecyclerView. At some cases the RecyclerView will be empty and therefore if I click on the position with `0` index it will fail. How do I write a test like this? To check first if the `recyclerView` not empty and then click on the specific position?

Comment: Your test should not call error if recyclerview is empty?

Comment: @Dmitriy yes. I want to ensure that: 1. The list if empty   2. Ahe user added an element   3. Now the list should exactly one element. How to do it? :-/

Comment: Slava, only after I posted the answer I understood that different people asked a question and wrote a comment above))) Look at the answer. If you could not adapt it for your case, than write me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a little bit different scenarios in question and in the comment.

Let's implement the next test scenario:
If recycler view does not contain anything, do nothing. If recycler view has at least one element, click on the first.

```
@Rule
public final ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(YourActivity.class);

@Test
public void testSample(){
    if (getRVcount() > 0){
        onView(withId(R.id.our_recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
    }
}

private int getRVcount(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.our_recycler_view);
    return recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
}
```

Comment: getting nullpointer exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.getItemCount()' on a null object reference

Comment: What if I have transitioned from activity A to activity B and recyclerView is in activity B? How to get its reference?

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I think it's better to check with **check** method. An example is given below.

```
@Test
 fun mainActivityTest() {   
    val yourRecycler = onView(
        allOf(

            childAtPosition(
                withClassName(`is`("androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout")),
                0
            ),
            instanceOf(RecyclerView::class.java)
        )
    )
    yourRecycler.check { view, noViewFoundException ->
                noViewFoundException?.apply {
                    throw this
                }
                assertTrue(view is RecyclerView &&
                    view.adapter != null && view.adapter?.itemCount?:-1 > 0
                )

            }
    }
```